# ¿Como llamar a una conexion Mysqli en diferente funciones?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

estoy migrando mi web de mysql a mysqli, antes tenia un archivo llamado db.php el cual tenia esta conexion a base de datos:
**db.php**

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost"; // El host
$dbuser = "root"; // El usuario
$dbpass = ""; // El Pass
$db = "web"; // Nombre de la base

$connect=mysql_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass"); // se conecta con la db
mysql_select_db("$db")or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

luego tenia un script con difrentes funciones llamado operaciones.php en el cual hacia un include al inicio para llamar la conexion y luego las funciones y sus respectivos codigos:

```
<?php
include("db.php")
function retornar_tipo_usuario(){

            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT
                perfiles.perfiles_id as id_perfil
                FROM
                usuarios
                INNER JOIN perfiles ON (usuarios.usuarios_id_perfil=perfiles.perfiles_id)");


          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $id_tipo_usuario=$row["id_perfil"];
            return $id_tipo_usuario;
            }

}
?>
```

hasta ahi todo me funcionaba bien pero ahora estoy usando mysqli y hago el mismo procedimiento pero al ejecutar el query me dice que es null, osea que no esta tomando la conexion a la base de datos

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost"; // El host
$dbuser = "root"; // El usuario
$dbpass = ""; // El Pass
$db = "web"; // Nombre de la base
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser,$dbpass, $db);
if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
die( "Fallo la conexión a MySQL: (" . $mysqli -> mysqli_connect_errno()
. ") " . $mysqli -> mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

operaciones.php

```
<?php
include("db.php")
    function retornar_tipo_usuario(){

                $sql=("SELECT
                    perfiles.perfiles_id as id_perfil
                    FROM
                    usuarios
                    INNER JOIN perfiles ON (usuarios.usuarios_id_perfil=perfiles.perfiles_id)");

              $sql = $mysqli->query($sql);
              while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                    $id_tipo_usuario=$row["id_perfil"];
                return $id_tipo_usuario;
                }

    }
?>
```

luego tengo varias funciones mas pero ninguna me conecta y me arroja el siguiente error:  `Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in`

Comment: Probaste agregando la variable a la funcion? function retornar_tipo_usuario(){ global $mysqli; $sql=....

Comment: Un Singleton con la conexión podría ser una solución

Comment: @JDev crear una clase para las consultas. Manejar todo como objetos y colocarlo de forma global.

Comment: Hola @DMAVE, pero tengo muchas funciones, osea que me tocaria agregar esa variable a todas las funciones?

Comment: Probaste usando una variable global? desde el archivo de conexión definir la variable de $mysqli como `global $mysqli;`

Comment: voy a probar de esa forma a ver como me va y te cuento, gracias @TppShaka77

Comment: @TppShaka77 justo lo que coloque en el primer comentario :) solo que en los comentarios no toma los espacios.

Comment: Bah, apenas me di cuenta @DMAVE jaja, justamente.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder hacer uso de una variable que viene de un documento incluido o procedente de otra parte del documento dentro de una función cuando es llamada usamos el la declaración `global`

Archivo db.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost"; // El host
$dbuser = "root"; // El usuario
$dbpass = ""; // El Pass
$db = "web"; // Nombre de la base
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser,$dbpass, $db);
if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
die( "Fallo la conexión a MySQL: (" . $mysqli -> mysqli_connect_errno()
. ") " . $mysqli -> mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Archivo de la función:

```
<?php
include("db.php")


function retornar_tipo_usuario(){
       global $mysqli;
       $sql=("SELECT
                perfiles.perfiles_id as id_perfil
                FROM
                usuarios
                INNER JOIN perfiles ON (usuarios.usuarios_id_perfil=perfiles.perfiles_id)");

      $sql = $mysqli->query($sql);
      while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                $id_tipo_usuario=$row["id_perfil"];
            return $id_tipo_usuario;
      }
}
?>
```

De ese modo puedes provechar la declaración de la conexión en las funciones que necesites.

Otra forma sería crear una función en tu archivo db.php:

```
<?php
 function db_connect() {

 $dbhost = "localhost"; // El host
 $dbuser = "root"; // El usuario
 $dbpass = ""; // El Pass
 $db = "web"; // Nombre de la base
 $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser,$dbpass, $db);
 if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
 die( "Fallo la conexión a MySQL: (" . $mysqli -> mysqli_connect_errno(). ") " . $mysqli -> mysqli_connect_error());
 }

 return $mysqli;
}
?>
```

Y ya desde las funciones:

```
<?php
include("db.php")


function retornar_tipo_usuario(){
       $mysqli = db_connect();
       $sql=("SELECT
                perfiles.perfiles_id as id_perfil
                FROM
                usuarios
                INNER JOIN perfiles ON (usuarios.usuarios_id_perfil=perfiles.perfiles_id)");

      $sql = $mysqli->query($sql);
      while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                $id_tipo_usuario=$row["id_perfil"];
            return $id_tipo_usuario;
      }
}
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda. Me funcionó creando la variable global y ya pude seguir migrando mis funciones. De nuevo muchas gracias a todos y saludes